# How to change or override openshift.conf in Python 3.3 cartridge

Tags: python, wsgi, openshift

I want to deploy an open source project on OpenShift, I did not write the application. Openshift seems hard coded to look for the wsgi script here:

WSGIScriptAlias / "/var/lib/openshift/5320e280e0b8cd9e9a000362/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi/application"

any attempt to change openshift.conf gets wiped out when the cartridge reloads or restarts.

I need this directive to be

WSGIScriptAlias / "/var/lib/openshift/5320e280e0b8cd9e9a000362/app-root/runtime/repo/myapp/wsgi.py"

I prefer not to have to hack the app, I don't want to have to worry about future changes upstream. The must be a way to change this setting but I've spent hours searching to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this release blog which explains how to use the `OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_WSGI_APPLICATION` environment variable to change your wsgi entry point: https://www.openshift.com/blogs/openshift-online-march-2014-release-blog