# What is the entry point that Apache mod_wsgi on OpenShift Online is looking for?

Tags: python-2.7, openshift, mod-wsgi

I've got an `OpenShift Python 2.7` application that I am guessing uses `mod_wsgi`.

Is it possible to ssh in to OpenShift Online and view the `.conf` files located somewhere like:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/
```

I am wanting to see which `.wsgi` file Apache looks for as defined in WSGIScriptAlias.

Perhaps it just looks for `/wsgi/application`?

A few posts indicate that changes have been made recently to the structure of Python applications, but they may not effect my older version:

[How to change or override openshift.conf in Python 3.3 cartridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384096/how-to-change-or-override-openshift-conf-in-python-3-3-cartridge)

https://blog.openshift.com/openshift-online-march-2014-release-blog/

[WSGI Application not found on OpenShift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109026/wsgi-application-not-found-on-openshift)

Ideally, I'm trying to comprehend the order in which these files are executed and their functions:

- `/wsgi/application`
- `/wsgi/my-bottle-application`
- `setup.py`
- `setup.pyc`
- `setup.pyo`

**UPDATE**

This indicates the entry point is `wsgi/application`:

https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_WSGI_APPLICATION

I'd still be interested to know the order of execution of the above files and exactly what `setup.py` does and how it is executed - ie there are no references to it in `application` so how is it 'called'?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this you can set your entry point: https://blog.openshift.com/openshift-online-march-2014-release-blog/

Python

For python app’s we’ve made some similar changes:

We got rid of wsgi/, wsgi/static/, data/ and libs/ directories.
You can use wsgi.py instead of wsgi/application as the default WSGI entry-point.
We’ve discarded the README.md file that can often conflict with an upstream file of the same name.
New OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_WSGI_APPLICATION to set an alternative WSGI entry-point.

```
wsgi.py             WSGI entry-point (configurable by $OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_WSGI_APPLICATION)
setup.py            Standard setup.py, specify deps here
.openshift/         Location for OpenShift specific files
    action_hooks/   See the Action Hooks documentation
    markers/        See the Markers section below
```

For more information on environment variables on OpenShift Online: https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-environment-variables.html

Comment: And I just came across this link that shows you how you to set environment variables, a very cool feature:  https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202399310-How-to-create-and-use-environment-variables-on-the-server-

Comment: Exactly what goes in `OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_WSGI_APPLICATION`? Just the directory where `wsgi.py` sits or should the filename be included as well? As of today, OS lacks an official, clear and up-to-date tutorial on how to setup and deploy a Django application.

Answer (score 1):

Example that worked for me using the `OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_WSGI_APPLICATION` variable:

```
rhc env-set     OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_WSGI_APPLICATION="${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}/server/wsgi.py" --app MyApp
```